# Passing cookies to httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

Is it possible to pass cookies to `HttpWebRequest` without using property `HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer`?

For some reasons, I don't have access to some object properties including `HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer`. I do have access to `HttpWebRequest` class and `CookieContainer` class.

Comment: `I dont have access to some object properties including HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer`. That's strange. `CookieContainer` is already around for a while. Which framework version are you using?

Comment: The reason for not having access to this property is known to me. I am just looking for a different way to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please show some code. How can we tell why you wouldn't have access to the properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to ignore the existence of an existing mechanism and reinvent the wheel, possibly including bugs solved by the existing implementation.

Setting cookies is trivial though:

```
request.Headers["Cookie"] = "foo=bar";
```

Just as reading them from the response:

```
string cookieHeader = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
```